Spin Representations and Tensor Representation
I've been learning some representation theory and I am confused about when (if ever) spin representations are also tensor representations.
Bröcker and tom Dieck's book Representations of Compact Lie groups says:
Let $V$ be a faithful representation of $G$ and let $\bar{V}$ be its conjugate representation.
Every irreducible representation of a compact Lie group $G$ in some $V(k,l)$, where
$$ V(k,l) = (V \otimes \cdots \otimes V) \otimes (\bar{V} \otimes \cdots \otimes \bar{V})$$
has $k$ factors of $V$ and $l$ factors of $\bar{V}$.
Since the Spin group, O(n) and SO(n) are all compact, I think that all of their irreducible representations should be contained in some tensor representation $V(k,l)$. However the wikipedia article on tensor representations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_representation) says:
"For orthogonal groups, the tensor representations are contrasted with the spin representations." which suggests that this is not true.
Questions 1) Can each irreducible representation of $G$ with an arbitrary highest weight be given as a tensor representation? Where $G = O(n),SO(n),Spin(n)$, if these cases are differ, is this because of the (simply) connectedness? I think the answer to this is "yes"
2) If the answer to the above is "yes", then what is the correct interpretation of the wikipedia quote?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

The result you mention is true. But the spin representation is not a representation of $SO(n)$. There is a homomorphism $\operatorname{Spin}(n) \rightarrow SO(n)$, but not the other way around. So any representation of $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ is contained in the tensor algebra of the Spin representation.
Since the homomorphism $\operatorname{Spin}(n) \rightarrow SO(n)$ is not injective, the representation of $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not faithful. Therefore the result does not apply. On the other hand, due to the non-existence of a homomorphism $SO(n) \rightarrow \operatorname{Spin}(n)$, the spin representation is not a representation of $SO(n)$, and not covered by the result.
As you might have realized, this means that the analagous result does not hold if you translate everything to the Lie algebra level.
